# Sitecore dashboard images are not loading

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

Recently have upgraded the Sitecore instance from 9.3 to 10.3 and post upgrade dashboard icons are not loading. When I inspect the broken image and the image loading from `temp` folder(`https://instance/temp/iconcache/launchpadicons/48x48/xanalytics.png`)

[image]

When I check the Network tab all the images are showing 500 exceptions.

[image]

To resolve this i did clean, link database and did complete indexing also.
If anyone faced a similar issue please do let me know.

If I add `-/` before temp folder image loading fine(`https://instance/-/temp/iconcache/launchpadicons/48x48/xanalytics.png`)

Comment: After migration have you rebuilt indexes?

Comment: If the issue still persists after applying the below suggestion, I would copy the images from the Vanilla temp folder and replace them in the upgraded temp folder and try.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the Nuget packge reference `SharpZipLib` library version is compatible with Sitecore 10.3. The OOTB(vanilla) Sitecore 10.3 uses `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll` with version 1.3.2.

[image]

Reference: [Sitecore Launchpad icons missing](https://cookingwithsitecore.com/2022/05/30/sitecore-launchpad-icons-missing/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sumit, I checked this article before publishing this question. ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll version is 1.3.2 only in my current Sitecore 10.3 version. I am suspecting something else causing this issue.

Comment: Also check the `/temp` folder permission, sometime permission cause the issue. Check the <customHandlers> in Sitecore.config value of `trigger="-/temp/"`

Answer (score 0):

You should also verify the following handler in your `web.config` file.

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_icon.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.IconRequestHandler" />
```

Also you can try running the Clean up databases from the Control Panel.

Hope this will help to resolve your issue.